# Monitors do not stay asleep Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, lock-screen, 19.04

I am not very Linux savvy, but I am enjoying Ubuntu full time now, it is working great. With one exception I make everything work perfectly.

I cannot, however, get my monitors to stay in sleep mode after inactivity. They go to sleep but are waken up imminently without any input from my side. If the system happens to be locked (Super+L) they go to sleep again after a short while but are waken up imminently again and go into some sort of disco (dingo) loop.

I can make a short video if that helps, but I do not know what I can do to debug the issue.
I have custom build PC, with Radeon RX570 on open drivers, two monitors one on HDMI, other is connected by Display Port.
I tried to disconnect one of them, no change.

Please let me know if you have any idea what can I try, or if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an RX570 with 2 monitors and have the same problem. I don't have a fix (apart from possibly to set amdgpu.dc=0 as mentioned in the links below). It seems to be this bug:

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109246

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1790861

Comment: Thanks, somehow I did not find it during my research. mdgpu.dc=0 looks like decent workaround, but unfortunately it broke Display Port sound that I was using. But it is good to know that it is a bug, not a configuration problem, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue with Ubuntu 22.04 so switched to Mint Cinnamon and surprisingly had the same exact issue. I have two monitors one via hdmi and the other via displayport. Windows 10/11 had no issue putting both to sleep.

So here is how I fixed the issue. On the displayport monitor I also have a Nintendo Switch connected via hdmi which is always off. On the other monitor connected via hdmi, I changed the input source from auto to hdmi and voila both monitors go into sleep right on cue. Try it :)